# is there a way to make some pages accessible by certain logged in users only in Magento 2.4.4?

Tags: magento

So I want to create page #1 as a content page in magento and I want only certain logged in users to be able to view this content not every logged in user

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell from your question, **you wish to restrict access to certain pages and allow access only to a selection of users.**

You could create Customer Groups and use an extension to assign certain pages only to certain customer groups.

Quick look around the interweb and I've found this extension: https://www.extensionhut.com/cms-page-by-customer-group-magento-2.html
(I have no experience of or connection with this company)

Good luck :)